# Is there a way to cast _io.TextIOWrapper to an integer in Python

Tags: python, file

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

f = int(f)
```

i am trying to compare what is the document with a number e.g. in the document there is 4 and I want to compare it like this

```
if 5 < f
```

Comment: `int(f.read())`?

Answer (score 1):

[`_io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) is a file object, created by `open`. You actually want to read *its contents* into a string and then convert *that* to an int.

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    n = int(f.read())

print(n, 5 < n)  # example
```

By the way, it's good practice to open files with a `with` statement. See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the Python Tutorial for the basics.